# How to custom indent JSON?

Tags: python, json

I want to be able to indent a JSON file in a way where the first key is on the same line as the opening bracket, by deafult, a json.dump() function puts it in a new line.

For example, if the original file was:

```
[
    {
        "statusName": "CO_FILTER",
        "statusBar": {}
```

I want it to start like this:

```
[
  { "statusName": "CO_FILTER",
    "statusBar":{}
```

Comment: Why do you care how the JSON is formatted?

Comment: I have never seen any JSON formatted with the first key/value pair on the same line as an opening curly bracket. Is there a particular reason that you want this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the standard `json` module. You can specify the amount of indentation for each level, but not the newline style.

Comment: There's a regular expression you can do with the `re` module, but I don't think there's a way to do this with just the `json` module

Comment: It's open source, so it shouldn't be hard for you to customize it.

Comment: pprint (pretty print) does something like this... but why?

Comment: Thank you for the insight. The main purpose of doing this is for readability within text editors. The actual JSON file is pretty huge and so collapsing it hides the first key. If the key is on the same line as the bracket, it becomes easier to expand then and see which object to take a look at. I read somewhere that this might be possible with regex but don't seem to know how to do so.

Comment: @Barmar Here's a somewhat similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746537/json-force-every-opening-curly-brace-to-appear-in-a-new-separate-line

Comment: Check your IDE settings, it might have an option to do this.

Comment: @Barmar Doing this in Spyder and unfortunately it doesn't support anything like that. What route would you suggest? Regex replacement or adding a custom json class to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you wanted to custom format it, you will most likely have to make/add onto the JSON library, just like the Google Json formatter and many others. But for the most part, its not like a value you can change on demand, it will either be included in another Json library apart from the default library from python. Maybe search for different python Json libraries that dumps Json the way you like.